# Sort an array of objects according to two properties values

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an array of objects:

```
let items = [
  { name: 'eric', type: 'comparable',  value: 1 },
  { name: 'bob', type: 'comparable', value: 4 },
  { name: 'michael', type: 'comparable', value: 0 },
  { name: 'john', type: 'comparable', value: 3 },
  { name: 'brad', type: 'incomparable', value: null },
  { name: 'james', type: 'incomparable', value: 5},
  { name: 'martin', type: 'comparable', value: 2 },
  { name: 'chris', type: 'comparable', value: null }
];
```

I want to sort my array so that the objects can be sorted by:

- First, according to "type" property -> if it's = "Comparable"   -> sort it according to the "value" property
- Second, according to the "value" property -> if it's null make it in the bottom of the array

by the "value" attribute, and if it's null, make the object in the bottom of the array, to be like this:

```
  { name: 'michael', type: 'comparable', value: 0 },
  { name: 'eric', type: 'comparable',  value: 1 },
  { name: 'martin', type: 'comparable', value: 2 },
  { name: 'john', type: 'comparable', value: 3 },
  { name: 'bob', type: 'comparable', value: 4 },
  { name: 'chris', type: 'comparable', value: null },
  { name: 'brad', type: 'incomparable', value: null },
  { name: 'james', type: 'incomparable', value: 5}
```

I've done this:

```
items.sort((a, b) => {
    return (a.value===null)-(b.value===null) || +(a.value>b.value)||-(a.ordre<b);
});
```

But like that I'm sorting always according to the "value" property, I want that it looks first for the property

(I won't use loadash)

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: Some of your types are 'incomparable'.  How do those play into the sorting logic?

Comment: Is your question specific to either ES6 or ES5? If a feature from ES2016 (aka ES7) was available to answer your question, would that be ruled out? If not, remove the version specific tags from the question.

Comment: "I want that it looks first for the property" -- I feel like there's a word missing there. I think it's "type" but figured you'd know best. Also, shouldn't `{ name: 'brad', type: 'incomparable', value: null }` be the last value in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally find it easier to read if the logic reads similar to the way you describe it. In this example I've tried to take the requirements as you've described it into a series of `if` statements instead of a single logical expression:

```js
let items = [
  { name: 'eric', type: 'comparable',  value: 1 },
  { name: 'bob', type: 'comparable', value: 4 },
  { name: 'michael', type: 'comparable', value: 0 },
  { name: 'john', type: 'comparable', value: 3 },
  { name: 'brad', type: 'incomparable', value: null },
  { name: 'james', type: 'incomparable', value: 5},
  { name: 'martin', type: 'comparable', value: 2 },
  { name: 'chris', type: 'comparable', value: null }
];

console.log(items.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.type === 'comparable' && b.type === 'comparable') {
    if (a.value == null) return 1;
    return a.value - b.value;
  }
  if (a.type === 'comparable') return -1;
  return 1;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `localeCompare` of the `type`, and then do a boolean short-circuit in case the types are the same. In the second part of the expression, you can evaluate the `value`, coercing `null` to `Infinity` to move it to the end.

```js
const items = [
  { name: 'eric', type: 'comparable',  value: 1 },
  { name: 'bob', type: 'comparable', value: 4 },
  { name: 'michael', type: 'comparable', value: 0 },
  { name: 'john', type: 'comparable', value: 3 },
  { name: 'brad', type: 'incomparable', value: null },
  { name: 'james', type: 'incomparable', value: 5},
  { name: 'martin', type: 'comparable', value: 2 },
  { name: 'chris', type: 'comparable', value: null }
];

items.sort((a, b) => a.type.localeCompare(b.type)
  || (a.value != null ? a.value : Infinity) - (b.value != null ? b.value : Infinity));

console.log(items);
```